# When I try to ask a new question, the form is filled out with details of a question I asked earlier

Tags: support, asking

I clicked on the Ask Question Mothership on the parent site, and the form was already filled out with information for [a question I have already asked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/what-is-the-most-powerful-non-beam-spell-in-magicka).

I asked that question days ago.  I'm not sure whether this is Chrome trying to be helpful and remembering the data I filled out or something relating to StackExchange.

Has anyone else experienced something like this?

Comment: [related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)

Answer (score 2):

As badp pointed out, this is likely a saved draft

[Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting)

There is one draft per site, per user, per type of post (question, answer).

Drafts are automatically saved every 45 seconds.

Comment: But the point is that I actually asked the question already.  Shouldn't the draft be discarded when the question gets asked?

Comment: sounds like a race condition...